Call function after signal value change
I have a component with a simple login form.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    ...
  ],
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrl: './login.component.scss',
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private formService: FormService,
    private appUserStore: AppUserStore,
  ) {
    this.isLoading = this.appUserStore.isLoading;

    effect(() => {
      if (this.appUserStore.isLogged()) {
        this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
      }
    });
  }

  returnUrl = '/';
  isLoading = signal(false).asReadonly();

  loginForm: FormGroup<LoginForm> = new FormGroup<LoginForm>({
    login: new FormControl('', {
      validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)],
      nonNullable: true,
    }),
    password: new FormControl('', {
      validators: [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(4),
        Validators.maxLength(50),
      ],
      nonNullable: true,
    }),
  });

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
  }

  onLogin() {
    this.appUserStore.login(this.loginForm.getRawValue());
  }

}

A simple user state store was prepared for authorization and storage of user state. The store was created based on NgRx SignalState, based on the documentation signal-state. My user state store is not complete yet.
interface AppUserState {
  user: User;
  isLoading: boolean;
  isLogged: boolean;
  tokens: Tokens;
}

const initialState: AppUserState = {
  user: new User(),
  isLoading: false,
  isLogged: false,
  tokens: new Tokens('', '', 0),
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AppUserStore {
  private readonly state = signalState<AppUserState>(initialState);
  private readonly authService = inject(AuthApiService);
  private readonly tokenCookieService = inject(TokenCookieService);

  readonly user = this.state.user;
  readonly isLogged = this.state.isLogged;
  readonly isLoading = this.state.isLoading;

  readonly login = rxMethod<LoginData>(
    pipe(
      tap(() => patchState(this.state, { isLoading: true })),
      exhaustMap((loginData: LoginData) => {
        return this.authService.login(loginData).pipe(
          tapResponse({
            next: (loginResponse) => {
              this.tokenCookieService.saveTokensCookie(loginResponse.tokens);
              patchState(this.state, {
                user: loginResponse.user,
                tokens: loginResponse.tokens,
                isLogged: loginResponse.user.id > 0,
              });
            },
            error: (error) => {
              this.resetState();
              console.log(error);
            },
            finalize: () => patchState(this.state, { isLoading: false }),
          }),
        );
      }),
    ),
  );

  private readonly resetState = () => {
    this.tokenCookieService.deleteTokensCookie();
    patchState(this.state, { ...initialState });
  };
}


Theoretically the component works as expected. After changing the login state, it redirects to the next url.
My main question is whether "effect" used to detect a change in the user's login state is a correct solution.
While searching for a solution on the Internet, I came across an opinion that "effect" should be used in specific cases. You should use "computed" to react to a change in the signal value, but I was unable to achieve the expected behavior of the component.
I know that you can use "toObservable" from rxjs-interop to transform the signal to an observable, and then make a subscription. But is this a necessary and the only correct solution?

So your code works.
You are using effect for redirection.
The effect is a good choice when you want to perform side effects/actions when a signal changes.
So using effect for redirection is correct. Using an observable sequence is possible but effect  seems simpler.

You can use computed when you want to derive other state variable/signals from an existing signal. They are computed based on the original signal. Performing redirection is a bad idea in a computed, since it defeats the original purpose for which computed is designed to handle.

Thank you for your answer. Yes, "effect" is easier to use, that's why I chose this method.
